# Is it possible to use multiple formats within a single (formula-based) cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I see that by highlighting a portion of the text inside a cell different formats can be applied (cool!).

But, is there a way to do this when the values are generated by a function?

Here's the look I'm going for:

[image]

[Here is my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OmDLtg4zHgWgeyRVPJkqmmEC4JYY0RmmabZY761yML8/edit?usp=sharing).

You can see there is a cell with the same values to the left that uses a formula.

Comment: At this time it's not possible to apply text format to parts of the result of a formula.

Answer (score 1):

> At this time it's not possible to apply text format to parts of the result of a formula. – Rubén Mar 6 at 11:36

Separate cells however can achieve a similar appearance:

[image: WA103431 example]